# Perl regex which grabs ALL double-letter occurrences in a line

Tags: regex, perl

Still plugging away at teaching myself Perl.  I'm trying to write some code that will count the lines of a file that contain double letters and then place parentheses around those double letters.

Now what I've come up with will find the first occurrence of double letters, but not any other ones.  For instance, if the line is:

> Amp, James Watt, Bob Transformer, etc. These pioneers conducted many

My code will render this:

> 19 Amp, James Wa(tt), Bob Transformer, etc. These pioneers conducted many

The "19" is the count (of lines containing double letters) and it gets the "tt" of "Watt" but misses the "ee" in "pioneers".

Below is my code:

```
$file = '/path/to/file/electricity.txt';        
open(FH, $file) || die "Cannot open the file\n";        

my $counter=0;

while (<FH>) {
    chomp();
    if (/(\w)\1/) {
        $counter += 1;
        s/$&/\($&\)/g;
        print "\n\n$counter $_\n\n";
    } else {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}

close(FH);
```

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 4):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my $file = '/path/to/file/electricity.txt';        
open my $fh, '<', $file;        

my $counter = 0;

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if (/(\w)\1/) {
        $counter++;
        s/
          (?<full>
               (?<letter>\p{L})
               \g{letter}
          )
        /($+{full})/xg;
        $_ = $counter . ' ' . $_;
    }
    say;
}
```

You are overlooking a few things. [strict and warnings](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=111088); 5.010 (or higher!) for [say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html); [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/autodie-2.10/lib/autodie.pm) so you don't have to keep typing those 'or die'; [Lexical filehandles](http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2005-10-03.html) and the [three-argument form of open](http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2005-11-17.html); A bit nitpicky, but [knowing when (not) to use parens for function calls](http://books.google.com/books?id=gJf9tI2mytIC&pg=PT35&lpg=PT35&dq=perl+parens+built-ins&source=bl&ots=Hk6egIrtgt&sig=bVOAlIV7bCj_HAu_DQAtRHvBse8&hl=es&ei=q5EiTcnPFoKC8gbl9MykAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false); Understanding why you [shouldn't use $&](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24&); The [autoincrement operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement)..

But on the regex part specifically, <strike>$& is only set on matches (m//), not substitution</strike> Actually no, ysth is right as usual. Sorry!

(I took the liberty of modifying your regex a bit; it makes use of named captures - (?) instead of bare parens, accessed through \g{} notation inside the regex, and the [%+](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) hash outside of it - and Unicode-style properties - \p{Etc}). A lot more about those in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perluniprops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html), respectively.

Comment: $& most certainly is set on substitution

Comment: ..and that's what I get for running my mouth like a turd. I have no idea why $& is doing what it does, then. I tried this: `C:\>perl -E "use re 'eval'; $_ = q!Amp, James Watt, Bob Transformer, etc. These pioneers conducted many!; /(\w)\1/; say qq!pre[$&] !; s/(?{ print qq!preinter[$&] ! })$&(?{ print qq!postinter[$&] ! })/say qq!subst[$&] !; qq!($&)!/eg; say qq!post[$&] !; say"` But I'm now more baffled than before.

Comment: Good answer, but the syntax/use of named regexes might be too complicated for someone just learning perl, i've been programming in perl for 2 years and have never come across them :P

Comment: @Charles Just because you've never come across named captures doesn't make them complicated. At worst they have a slightly confusing syntax, which can be tidied with `/x` and good use of whitespace. But their real power is that they make subsequent code far less cryptic, and make regexes robust to addition or subtraction of capture groups at a later date.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks a lot for the detailed response.  As I stated above I'm using the tutorial at http://comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl which goes over the $`, $&, and $' special variables and I assumed that it did so because the solution required the use of one or more of them.  Bad assumption on my part.

Comment: One question, why bother with the autoincrement function?  It saves me one letter of typing and offers no added functionality, certainly in this case.  And given that there's a difference between "++counter" and "counter++" that can introduce subtle errors into your code I would think the best advice would be to avoid it.  But then, I am but a nube...

Comment: @phileas fogg: I love doing those link waterfalls, so no need to thank me. Unfortunately I can't open your link from this computer, but I'll take a wild guess and say that it sucks -- it's a shame, but a lot of tutorials for Perl out there just.. Suck. People start learning Perl using those, and get screwed over: It happens all the time, which is just distressing. If you can get your hands of Learning Perl, 5th edition, you'll do yourself a huge favor - But if you can't, this link gets thrown around beginner@perl.org pretty often: http://perl-begin.org/tutorials/

Comment: After reading your link on using 'strict' I'm left with the question, why would you use both 'strict' and 'warnings'?  Since 'strict' stops your code on the first error and 'warnings' lets it run they seem to fight one another and offer the same benefits.

Comment: @phileas fogg: I guess "because it looks pretty" is the main reason for the auto(in|de)crement. Generally you can do without them, minus for that one occassion where it'd be a pain if they weren't there. As for strict and warnings, they enforce different things - Exceptions raised by strict, such as using a variable without declaring it, will stop execution of your program - However, strict will only catch so much. For things that don't deserve a full exception, such as printing a declared, but undefined variable, you will want warnings. Try: `my $hello; print "[$hello]";` with warnings on/off

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a back reference:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $line = "this is a doubble letter test of my scrippt";

$line =~ s/([[:alpha:]])(\1)/($1$2)/g;

print "$line\n";
```

And now the test.

```
$ ./test.pl
this is a dou(bb)le le(tt)er test of my scri(pp)t
```

It works!

When you do a substitution, you use the `$1` to represent what is in the parentheses. When you are referring to a part of the regular expression itself, you use the `\1` form.

The `[[:alpha:]]` is a special POSIX class. You can find out more information by typing in

```
$ perldoc perlre
```

at the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating things by messing around with `$&`.  `s///g` returns the number of substitutions performed when used in scalar context, so you can do it all in one shot without needing to count matches by hand or track the position of each match:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = 'James Watt, a pioneer of wattage engineering';

my $doubles = $text =~ s/(\w)\1/($1$1)/g;

print "$doubles $text\n";
```

Output:

```
4 James Wa(tt), a pion(ee)r of wa(tt)age engin(ee)ring
```

**Edit:** OP stated in comments that the exercise in question says not to use `=~`, so here's a non-regex-based solution, since all regex matches use `=~` (implicitly or explicitly):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = 'James Watt, a pioneer of wattage engineering';

my $doubles = 0;
for my $i (reverse 1 .. length $text) {
    if (substr($text, $i, 1) eq substr($text, $i - 1, 1)) {
        $doubles++;
        substr($text, $i - 1, 2) = '(' . substr($text, $i - 1, 2) . ')';
    }
}

print "$doubles $text\n";
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I'm using http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl as a tutorial and the tutorial asks that a solution explicitly not use =~ match operator but instead use $_.  So that requirement lead me down the dead-end path I ended up on.

Comment: @phileas fogg: `if (/(\w)\1/)` is just shorthand for `if ($_ =~ /(\w)\1/)`, so your version is still using `=~` implicitly even if you don't actually see it on your screen. I suspect that this limitation was intended to get you to write a solution using the `substr` function instead of a regex, so I'll edit one into my answer. (Or maybe my suspicion is wrong... Can you give a link to the specific exercise? I don't seem to be able to find it.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using $& in the second regex which only matched the first occurance of a double letter set

```
 if (/(\w)\1/) { #first occurance matched, so the pattern in the replace regex will only be that particular set of double letters
```

Try doing something like this:
`s/(\w)\1/\($1$1\)/g;` instead of `s/$&/\($&\)/g;`

Full code after editing:

```
$file = '/path/to/file/electricity.txt';        
open(FH, $file) || die "Cannot open the file\n";        

my $counter=0;

while (<FH>) {
    chomp();
    if (s/(\w)\1/\($1$1\)/g) {
        $counter++;
        print "\n\n$counter $_\n\n";
    } else {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}

close(FH);
```

notice that you can use the s///g replace in a conditional statement which is true when a replace occurred.

Comment: I tried that originally and got a bunch of "uninitialized use of $1 in line x" warnings.

Comment: which version of perl are  you using?

Comment: Actually what I tried was the same code as I wrote above but used "$1" instead of $&.  This resulted in the warnings and it also grabbed the first instance of a double letter and then substituted "()" in all subsequent appearances of that letter in the line.

Comment: I see, edited with the full code so you know where the regex is supposed to go :)