# How to remove words with repeated characters from a string with a single regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to remove any words containing repeated characters from a string in Perl. I can use the `/e` flag:

```
$string =~ s/(\w+)/keys %{{map {$_,1} split '', $1}} == length $1 ? $1 : ""/ge;
```

Can this be done with a single regex, without `/e`?

Comment: This [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590248/perl-regex-which-grabs-all-double-letter-occurances-in-a-line) detects all the double letters, expand it to include more letters and match the blank space at both end before you subst it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string =~ s/\b\w*(\w)\w*\1\w*\b//g;
```

Looks weird, but works anyway.